Error retrieving Storage Account: Unexpected status 404 Not Found with Terraform and Azure
While deploying storage account data lake gen2 with service endpoints using Terraform on Azure, encountering a 404 Not Found error
resource "random_integer" "random_suffix1" {
  min = 10000
  max = 99999
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "dev_storage" {
  name                     = "inddatalakedev${random_integer.random_suffix1.result}"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.rg_analytics_dev_central_india.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.rg_analytics_dev_central_india.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  is_hns_enabled           = true
  public_network_access_enabled = false  
  infrastructure_encryption_enabled = true
  account_kind = "StorageV2"


  network_rules {
    default_action             = "Deny"
    virtual_network_subnet_ids = [
      azurerm_subnet.private-dev.id,
      azurerm_subnet.public-dev.id,
      azurerm_subnet.pe-subnet.id
    
    ]
  }
  depends_on = [azurerm_subnet.pe-subnet]
}


resource "azurerm_storage_account" "prod_storage" {
  name                     = "inddatalakeprod${random_integer.random_suffix1.result}"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.rg_analytics_prod_central_india.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.rg_analytics_prod_central_india.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  is_hns_enabled           = true
  public_network_access_enabled = false  
  infrastructure_encryption_enabled = true
  account_kind = "StorageV2"


  network_rules {
    default_action             = "Deny"
    virtual_network_subnet_ids = [
      azurerm_subnet.public.id,
      azurerm_subnet.private.id,
      azurerm_subnet.private-dev.id,
      azurerm_subnet.public-dev.id,
      azurerm_subnet.pe-subnet.id
 
    ]
  }
  depends_on = [azurerm_storage_account.dev_storage]
}


Error: retrieving Storage Account (Subscription: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX" │ Resource Group Name: "RG-Analytics-Dev-CentralIndia" │ Storage Account Name: "inddatalakedev27620"): unexpected status 404 (404 Not Found) with error: StorageAccountNotFound: The storage account inddatalakedev27620 was not found. │ │   with azurerm_storage_account.dev_storage, │   on storage.tf line 11, in resource "azurerm_storage_account" "dev_storage": │   11: resource "azurerm_storage_account" "dev_storage" {


The issue you’re facing is due to missing service endpoint on your Vnet and Snet as per the MSDoc Few network rules are restricting access to some subnets. so, to provide access to them we need to set service endpoints [Microsoft.Storage] without this we cannot access the storage account
In reference harshicorp documentation and SO link this is how I tried the script below
terraform script:
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "analytics-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg_analytics_dev_central_india.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg_analytics_dev_central_india.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "public-dev" {
  name                 = "public-dev"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg_analytics_dev_central_india.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.Storage"]
  depends_on           = [azurerm_virtual_network.vnet]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "private-dev" {
  name                 = "private-dev"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg_analytics_dev_central_india.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
  service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.Storage"]
  depends_on           = [azurerm_virtual_network.vnet]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "pe-subnet" {
  name                 = "pe-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg_analytics_dev_central_india.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.3.0/24"]
  service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.Storage"]
  depends_on           = [azurerm_virtual_network.vnet]
}


and then continue with rest of the configuration of storage account data lake gen2
Output


